# Keep getting random errors with elementary OS installer on laptop

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, laptop

I've been trying for a long time to get elementary OS freya 0.3.2 running on my HP Compaq NC2400 laptop (1.2ghz core duo, 2gb of ram), yet the installer keeps crashing and crashing. Sometimes I get an error that says that certain files that are being copied do not match their installation medium sources: other times i get an Errno 5. And when I get to the installing/configuring part, the installer always crashes. I've checked the SHA256 hash for the ISO, and it matches. I've also remade my installation USB numerous times, and it doesn't have any errors. What could be happening here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bad partition that your installing to. Possibly caused by a disk defect. What partitoning and filesystem are you using ?